# Make Kivy Data on Android Persistent

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm working on an Android app using Kivy, and an important part will be saving data that can be retrieved whenever the app launches. However, I want to make sure that if the app needs to update, the data isn't lost. I also would like to make it as easy as possible to transfer this saved file to a new device if a user gets a new phone. I know there's several different ways to save and retrieve data, but I was wondering if anyone had advice on the best way to make the data persistent and transferable. Thanks for your insight.

I haven't tried anything yet, I'm just looking for some advice before I get started.

Answer (score 1):

Given my experience, I see two ways to manage this problem:

1. You can use the library `androidstorage4kivy` to allow the user to load or export its own data file, per mail or per message, without having to search in the storage. This method requires the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in the buildozer.spec file. Here is a short extract of code showing the import and export function I use for this functionality. You can find a more complete version on the following repository: https://github.com/LupaDevStudio/TramwayCollector (in the settings_window.py file)

```py
import shutil
from androidstorage4kivy import SharedStorage, ShareSheet, Chooser

def export_collection():

    # Create the zip file
    shutil.make_archive("collection", "zip", PATH_DATA_FOLDER)

    # Copy it into the shared storage
    shared_storage = SharedStorage()
    file_to_share = shared_storage.copy_to_shared(
        "collection.zip", filepath="/collection.zip")

    # Share it
    shared_sheet = ShareSheet()
    shared_sheet.share_file(file_to_share)

def import_collection():
    # Create a file chooser
    chooser = Chooser(chooser_callback)
    # Open the file chooser for the user
    chooser.choose_content("application/zip")

def chooser_callback(shared_file_list):
    ss = SharedStorage()
    private_file = ss.copy_from_shared(shared_file_list[0])

    # Unpack the archive
    shutil.unpack_archive(private_file, PATH_DATA_FOLDER)
```

2. You can use a system of accounts and servers to store the data of the user. This is obviously more complicated and requires an online server and the permission from the users to collect their data. Alternatively, if you don't want to create your own server, you can use the Google Play account system which provides an API to manage the data of the users; it allows them to recover data on other devices with the same account. This can be done inside the Google Play Console when publishing the app.